# when enter string value it wont print please enter numeric value it just shows a name error name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
hours = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
rate = float(input("Enter Rate:"))
extra = 1.5 * (rate) * (hours - 40)

try:
    if hours > 40: 
        print "Pay: %r" % ((40) * (rate) + (extra)) 
    else:
        print "Pay: %r" % ((hours) * (rate))
except:
    print "Please enter numeric value!!!"
```

Comment: thanks for editing :)

Comment: try `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, it seems that you are using Python2.x, Also, the conversion of `str` to `float` in the line: `hours = float(input("Enter Hours:"))` should be inside the `try catch` block.

Comment: Your `try/except` should be around the place where you cast the strings to `float`.

Comment: wont work too value error : could not convert string into float

Comment: @amrayach: that's something new then. Did you actually enter a floating point string?

Comment: thanks guys ill give it another try